# Редирект ранга портов на другой сервер

Tags: linux, iptables

Как сделать редирект ранга портов на другой сервер?
Пример: все соединения с 20000 по 23000 порт перенаправлять на 2.3.4.5:ПОРТ(с 20000 по 23000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно только если другой_сервер будет посылать ответы через первый сервер (то есть, фактически, это случай, когда первый сервер является default gateway'ем для другого_сервера (этого можно добиться также с помощью VPN).

Допустим, сервер1 имеет публичный адрес 188.1.1.5 (это тот адрес, на который будут приходить входящие коннекты на интересующие нас порты.

Допустим, сервер1 и сервер2 связаны между собой сетью 192.168.1.0, в которой сервер1 имеет адрес 192.168.1.1, а сервер2 — 192.168.1.2, причём 192.168.1.1 яляется default gw для сервер2.

В этом случае настройка iptables на сервер1 будет выглядеть так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000:23000 -m state --state NEW -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
```

Естественно, на сервере1 должен быть разрешён IP forwarding.

Comment: написал https://hastebin.com/raw/banavovubu и не работает

Comment: Первая фраза в моём ответе принципиальна.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё один вариант — установить на сервер1 nginx, сконфигурированный как [TCP proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/).
Это решение далеко от первоначальной постановки задачи, но работоспособно и без выполнения условия с default gateway.
У него два "но":

1. Все соединения на сервер2 будут приходить с адреса сервера1
2. Я не проверял его на себе :)